# MM/DD (Including Leap Year) RegEx Pattern

Tags: regex

It took me a while to find the answer to MM/DD including Leap Year (Feb 29th).

So I figured I'd make a question and answer my own question for other's to view.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the following

```
^((0?[1-9]|1[012])\/(0?[1-9]|1\d|2[0-9])|(0?[13456789]|1[012])\/(29|30)|(0?[13578]|1[02])\/31)$
```

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte It works for me.  Can you give an example that fails?

Comment: Since you are the asker, it is your job to check it as accepted.

Answer (score 1):

Reg ex that matches all valid dates including leap years. Formats accepted mm/dd/yyyy or mm-dd-yyyy or mm.dd.yyyy format

[Flow for how this works](http://www.regexper.com/#%5E%28?%3a%28?%3a%28?:0?%5B13578%5D%7C1%5B02%5D%29%28%5C/%7C-%7C%5C.%2931%29%5C1%7C%28?%3a%28?:0?%5B1,3-9%5D%7C1%5B0-2%5D%29%28%5C/%7C-%7C%5C.%29%28?:29%7C30%29%5C2%29%29%28?%3a%28?:1%5B6-9%5D%7C%5B2-9%5D%5Cd%29?%5Cd%7B2%7D%29%24%7C%5E%28?:0?2%28%5C/%7C-%7C%5C.%2929%5C3%28?%3a%28?%3a%28?:1%5B6-9%5D%7C%5B2-9%5D%5Cd%29?%28?:0%5B48%5D%7C%5B2468%5D%5B048%5D%7C%5B13579%5D%5B26%5D%29%7C%28?%3a%28?:16%7C%5B2468%5D%5B048%5D%7C%5B3579%5D%5B26%5D%2900%29%29%29%29%24%7C%5E%28?%3a%28?:0?%5B1-9%5D%29%7C%28?:1%5B0-2%5D%29%29%28%5C/%7C-%7C%5C.%29%28?:0?%5B1-9%5D%7C1%5Cd%7C2%5B0-8%5D%29%5C4%28?%3a%28?:1%5B6-9%5D%7C%5B2-9%5D%5Cd%29?%5Cd%7B2%7D%29%24)

```
  ^(?:(?:(?:0?[13578]|1[02])(\/|-|\.)31)\1|(?:(?:0?[1,3-9]|1[0-2])(\/|-|\.)(?:29|30)\2))(?:(?:1[6-9]|[2-9]\d)?\d{2})$|^(?:0?2(\/|-|\.)29\3(?:(?:(?:1[6-9]|[2-9]\d)?(?:0[48]|[2468][048]|[13579][26])|(?:(?:16|[2468][048]|[3579][26])00))))$|^(?:(?:0?[1-9])|(?:1[0-2]))(\/|-|\.)(?:0?[1-9]|1\d|2[0-8])\4(?:(?:1[6-9]|[2-9]\d)?\d{2})$
```

Comment: Good regex, only OP wanted to match MM/DD. Might as well leave the answer here for historical reference.

Comment: @Amarnath: your second pattern match "01/00/2014"

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte have removed it for now.

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte can you check it now?

Comment: "02/31/1931" "04/31/1978" "07/14/1789" "1/01/2014" "01/1/2014"